# Error while running appium on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: ubuntu, npm, appium

I'm newbie to appium, I have already installed npm and node. When i run

```
"sudo npm install -g appium"
```

I get this error.

```
npm WARN engine hoek@2.16.3: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.40"} (current: {"node":"0.10.25","npm":"1.4.21"})

> appium-chromedriver@2.8.3 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-android-driver/node_modules/appium-chromedriver
> node install-npm.js

sh: 1: node: not found
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-android-driver/node_modules/lodash/utility/propertyOf.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 4.2.0-16-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "appium"
npm ERR! cwd /home/nevedha
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-android-driver/node_modules/lodash/utility/propertyOf.js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! appium-chromedriver@2.8.3 install: `node install-npm.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 127
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the appium-chromedriver@2.8.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the appium-chromedriver package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node install-npm.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls appium-chromedriver
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Linux 4.2.0-16-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "appium"
npm ERR! cwd /home/nevedha
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/nevedha/.npm/appium-adb/2.5.1/package.tgz
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/nevedha/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

could anybody help me out?

thanks for your time.

Comment: could you please share `npm-debug.log` as well

Comment: I updated my npm and the current version 3.8.6. And I get this error which says - "Failed at the appium-selendroid-driver@1.3.1 install script 'node ./bin/install.js" Here is the Logs:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/iywisfh7270l5qk/npm-debug.log?dl=0  Kindly help.